# Eclipse--How to Find Where a Defined Function Has Been Used

Tags: c++, eclipse, search

I am using eclipse for modifying a cpp project. Could you please tell me how can I find all the places a defined function has been used?
Already tried ctrl + alt + g and ctrl + h . But, they return everything in the workspace with the the searched name, not exactly usages of the desired function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried ctrl+shift+g ? that should find for all references to the selected identify.